# Open ball in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space.

(a) Show that for any $r>0$ and any $x,y ∈ X$, we have $B(x,r)⊆B(y,r+d(x,y))$.

Def: given any metric space $(X,d)$ and any point $x\in X$ and any $r>0$ the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$ is $B(x,r)$ $=$ {$x\in X: d(x,x_0)<r$}

so,

$B(x,r)⊆B(y,r+d(x,y))$

how would you difine $B(y,r+d(x,y))$ ?

where $d(x,y)=∣x_1−y_1∣+∣x_2−y_2∣$

(b) Show that for any distinct $x,y ∈ X$, we have $B(x, 1/2d(x,y))\cap B(y, 1/2d(x,y)) = \phi .$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one use triangle inequality. If $z\in B(x,r)$ then we know $d(z,y)\leq d(x,y)+d(x,z)$ it means $d(z,y)\leq d(x,y)+r$.

For the second one choose $z\in B(x, 1/2d(x,y))\cap B(y, 1/2d(x,y))$ then again with triangle inequality we have $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)< \frac{1}{2}d(x,y)+\frac{1}{2}d(x,y)=d(x,y)$ but it is not true $d(x,y)<d(x,y)$. So, we cannot find any $z\in B(x, 1/2d(x,y))\cap B(y, 1/2d(x,y))$ it means it is empty.

Comment: I think for second one you should exchange $1$ by $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: thank you, yes the second was false, it is 1/2. would you also apply the triangle inequality to this?

Comment: So the second one is exactly like the first one. I you solved it then nothing. If not then you can mention me and I will solve it for you.

Comment: sorry what do you mean in mentioning you?

Comment: @thisisme see the proof for $(b)$ section.

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Consider any point $z\in B(x,r)$, then $d(z,x)<r$. Now $$d(z,y)<d(z,x)+d(x,y)\\<r+d(x,y)$$ by triangle inequality. So $z\in B(y,r+d(x,y))$. So $z\in B(x,r)\subseteq B(y,r+d(x,y))$